# Define the undefined method of base class in derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a base class A and two classes B, C derived from A. Declaration of method func is given in class A. How can I define method func separately for B and C ?

```
class A {
public:
   void func();
};

class B : public A {
//some members
};

class C : public A {
//some members
};

//define B's func here without changing the definition of the three classes
//define C's func here without changing the definition of the three classes
```

Comment: This is a _very_ basic topic in C++ and is covered in books on C++. I suggest you pick up a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Not possible without using "virtual" directive. The address of A::func() has to be overwritten by B::func() or C::func() and can only be done if we do late binding.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the method you want to overwrite "virtual" or "pure virtual" and if a class has virtual methods, also the destructor must be virtual:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A{};
  virtual void func() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
  void func() {};
};

class C : public A {
  void func() {};
};
```

Comment: @newuser: Without changing, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot implement a member function for a class without it being declared in the class.

```
class A {
public:
   void func();
};

class B : public A {
//some members
};

class C : public A {
//some members
};

void B::func() {}
void C::func() {}
```

```
/tmp/164435074/main.cpp:17:9: error: out-of-line definition of 'func' does not match any declaration in 'B'
void B::func() {}
        ^~~~
/tmp/164435074/main.cpp:18:9: error: out-of-line definition of 'func' does not match any declaration in 'C'
void C::func() {}
        ^~~~
```